# Combines three fields with group_by with different fields

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have 3 data with the same name fields but with different values

```
  id   |  name  |    date    
------ | ------ | ----------- 
  1    |  john  |  2015-10-02 
  2    |  john  |  2016-09-10  
  3    |  john  |  2017-08-10
```

I want to combine into a single three value fields by name, and its value appears by fields year 2015, year 2016, year 2017. like the example below

```
  id   |  name  |     2015    |     2016     |     2017
------ | ------ | ----------- | ------------ | ----------- 
  1    |  john  |  2015-10-02 |  2016-09-10  |  2017-08-10
```

I tried using group_by but only 1 field values ​​that appear.
This my models.

```
function viewkal()  {
   $this->db->order_by('name','ASC');
   $this->db->group_by('name');
   $query = $this->db->get('mytabel');  
   return $query->result();                             
}
```

Comment: what is `$this->db`? I have no idea what it is but I think you may be able to chain the query eg: `$query = $this->db->get('mytabel')->order_by('name','ASC')->group_by('name');`

Comment: @Isaac `$this->db` to define the database in codeigniter models

Comment: What is the column type for date 1/2/3?

Comment: @AhmedEssam, the column type varchar

Answer (score 0):

You should use an aggegation function like max or min  for grouped by function

```
$this->db->select_max('date 1');
$this->db->select_max('date 2');
$this->db->select_max('date 3');
```

Comment: thanks @scaisEdce, however date1, data2, date3, contained in a table [ 'id', 'name', 'YEAR( date1 , data2 , date3 , )' I split by year, so they are difficult to use function

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom SQL query for this. Something like this will group concatente the fields:

```
SELECT name, 
GROUP_CONCAT(date1 SEPARATOR '') AS date1, 
GROUP_CONCAT(date2 SEPARATOR '') AS date2, 
GROUP_CONCAT(date3 SEPARATOR '') AS date3
FROM `mytable` GROUP BY name
```

We define the separator to be none, else we will have commas around the fields. This method works for string and date fields.To use a custom query in CodeIgniter pass the query to:

```
$this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");
```